# python pick and delete by item using dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary such as the one below, what is the best way to

1. Pick all those items which have a partial key `1d`
2. Then delete those items based on that key

   `c = {('1d','f1'):1.5,('1w','f1'):1.2,('1d','f2'):1.4}`

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> c = {('1d','f1'):1.5,('1w','f1'):1.2,('1d','f2'):1.4}
>>> {k: v for k, v in c.iteritems() if '1d' not in k}
{('1w', 'f1'): 1.2}
```

In py2.x use `c.iteritems()` as it returns an iterator, for py3.x you can use `c.items()`.

Note that `c.items()` will work in both versions.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> c = {('1d','f1'):1.5,('1w','f1'):1.2,('1d','f2'):1.4}
>>> {k: v for k, v in c.items() if k[0] != '1d'}
{('1w', 'f1'): 1.2}
```

For the general case use `if '1d' not in k`. In Python 2.x use `dict.iteritems` (an iterator instead of a list) instead

Comment: We can use `iteritems()` here for memory efficient solution.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The Python version wasn't mentioned so I went for a cross compatible solution

Answer (score 2):

please consider following methods

in python 2.7 and higher You can use dict comprehension

```
>>> c = {('1d','f1'):1.5,('1w','f1'):1.2,('1d','f2'):1.4}
>>> {k: v for k, v in c.items() if '1d' not in k}
{('1w', 'f1'): 1.2}
```

in python 2.6 and lower One should use generator instead dict

```
>>> c = {('1d','f1'):1.5,('1w','f1'):1.2,('1d','f2'):1.4}
>>> dict((k, v) for k, v in c.iteritems() if '1d' not in k)
{('1w', 'f1'): 1.2}
```